# Switching limit and integral in a min function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Let $f_n$ and $f$ be probability density functions such that  $f_n\rightarrow f$.

Set $F_n(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_n(t)d\mu(t)$ and $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)d\mu(t)$.

Define $l_n(x)=\min(f_n(x),f(x))$.

Then we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int l_n(x)d\mu(x)=\int\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}l_n(x)d\mu(x)$.

I'm not seeing why this is the case. Any hints?

Comment: Definition of $F_n$ and $F$ is not usefull?

Comment: Try the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  You have $0\le l_n(x)\le f(x)$ for all $n$ and all $x$, and $f$ is integrable.